# How can I bring my two bird companions back?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid, necromancy

Someone in my party was stupid and caused a massive meteor shower which killed lots of NPCs and my two hawk companions (I'm a druid).
They are dead but I really loved them, so much so my character went into mourning and now only wears black and such. 
I want the birds back, whether in  ghost form or normal (resurrected) form.

How can I bring my two hawk companions back?

Comment: Welcome to site. Take the [tour]. Answers are better when the question provides more information. So what's the druid's level? What resources are available to the druid? What resources does the DM allow players to use for their characters in the campaign? In a broader sense, what's stopping the druid from paying the cash for a couple of *raise dead* spells and having the birds brought back? Thank you for participating, and have fun.

Comment: Not anything helpful, but ghost hawks sound awesome. "Xerxes, Leonidas, search the city on ghostly wing!"

Comment: Definitely please explain more of your level and context and such - in D&D 3.5 there's a nearly infinite number of "bring someone back somehow" options.